How to pass parameter file to generic python task in Databricks Asset Bundle just like you would do with dbx using --conf-file
In DBX I was used to create one ingestion task and then have multiple yml files with different configs use in my deployment.yml like:
        tasks:
          - task_key: ingest_<source>_<table>
            job_cluster_key: job_cluster
            python_wheel_task:
              package_name: dbx_<source>_<layer>
              entry_point: <source>_ingestion_task
              parameters:
                - --conf-file
                - file:fuse://conf/deployments/<source>/tasks/<table>_config.yml


In the python (Task) I could access these parameters in the file like:
value = self.conf["<key>"]["<sub_key>"]
How can I do the same using Databricks Asset Bundles because I really need this. I have multiple generic ingestion functions which I need to create tasks for with separate parameters(files)

You can used named_parameters:
  tasks:
    - task_key: my_task
      existing_cluster_id: ${var.existing_cluster_id}
      python_wheel_task:
        package_name: my_package
        entry_point: my_entry_point
        named_parameters: { env: "${var.environment}", config_file: "my_config.yml"}

In your entrypoint, you can access the parameters as follows:
def entrypoint():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My description.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--env",
        help="Environment value to pass to all applications.",
        type=str,
        choices=["dev", "prd"],
        required=True,
        dest="environment",
    )
    parser.parse_args()
    print(args.environment)


If i understand correctly, you want to have the same functionality with asset bundles as you did previously in dbx, using the base class and the --conf-file parameter. this documentation describes how you can access properties of other mappings and do variable substitution to paramterize the environment
assuming the project structure:
- databricks.yml
- conf/deployments/<source>/tasks/<table>_config.yml
- rescources/demployment.yaml
- src/example/...
- tasks/example.py
- common.py # the file generated by dbx

and databricks.yml looks roughly like:
bundle:
  name: example_asset_bundle

targets:
  dev:
    ...
    workspace:
      root_path: /Users/${workspace.current_user.userName}/bundles/${bundle.name}/
      file_path: /Users/${workspace.current_user.userName}/bundles/${bundle.name}/files

you want to pass <table>_config.yml to the job. so in deployment.yml,
the parameters property would be:
deployment.yml
...# only including relevant part
        tasks:
          - task_key: ingest_<source>_<table>
            job_cluster_key: job_cluster
            python_wheel_task:
              package_name: dbx_<source>_<layer>
              entry_point: <source>_ingestion_task
              parameters: [ "--conf-file", "file:/Workspace${workspace.file_path}/conf/deployments/<source>/tasks/<table>_config.yml" ]

In addition, you would need to update the function reading the config file to use dbutils:
config = yaml.safe_load(self.dbutils.fs.head(conf_file))

